# XML: Problem with showing my created variables

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am facing one last problem with my first XML/XSL project:
I have succeded in creating a variable in which I have merged two data from two different elements: I have 100 instances of 2 different elements linked by a key 'ID', just a sample:

```
<data>
  <Exams>
    <Exam>
      <id>1</id>
      <ExamName>Data Management</ExamName>
      <ExamGrade>5</ExamGrade>
    </Exam>
....

<Student>
      <id>100</id>
      <Name>Audrie</Name>
      <National>International</National>
      <DataManagementGrade>4.9</DataManagementGrade>
    </Student>
  </Students>

</data>
```

SO I have 100 students and each of which took 1 exam, Student with 'id 1' took exam with 'id 1'

The student grade in 'DataManagementGrade' is merged with 'ExamGrade':

```
<xsl:variable name="examG" select="sum(key('examById', id)/ExamGrade) div 2
                  + sum(DataManagementGrade) div 2 "/>
```

When if I first try to show each variable 'examG' of each student it worked without any problem :
[examG = Application's Grade][1]

But when I reuse the same line to show it in a different windows: clicking on the "Result button" and then another button which opens the window that must show again the same variable examG for each student respectively it only shows me the variable examG of the first student for all student, here is the window for Brian (id 1) :
[For the first one it shows the correct variable][2]

But it shows the same variable for the others students too:
[Niels' Window][3]

Here is my body code:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">National / International</th>
      <th scope="col">Data Management Grade</th>
      <th scope="col">Entrance Exam's Subject</th>
      <th scope="col">Exam's Grade</th>
      <th scope="col">Application's Grade</th>
      <th scope="col">Application's Result</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>

    <xsl:for-each select="data/Students/Student">
      <tr>

        <xsl:variable name="examG" select="sum(key('examById', id)/ExamGrade) div 2
          + sum(DataManagementGrade) div 2 "/>

        <td>

          <xsl:value-of select="id"/></td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="Name"/></td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="National"/></td>
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="DataManagementGrade"/></td>

        <td><xsl:value-of select="key('examById', id)/ExamName"/></td>

        <td><xsl:value-of select="key('examById', id)/ExamGrade"/></td>

        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="$examG"/>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#id">
            Result

          </button>
        </td>

        <div class="modal fade" id="ad" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Admission(s)</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">

                <li class="list-group-item">

                  <xsl:value-of select="$examG"/>

                </li>

              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </tr>

    </xsl:for-each>

    <div class="modal fade" id="id" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Schools' information</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <ul class="list-group">

              <xsl:for-each select="data/Schools/School">
                <li class="list-group-item">
                  Ranking:

                  <xsl:value-of select="Ranking"/></li>
                <li class="list-group-item">
                  School:

                  <xsl:value-of select="SchoolName"/></li>
                <li class="list-group-item">
                  Admission Grade:

                  <xsl:value-of select="MinimumRequired"/></li>

              </xsl:for-each>
            </ul>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#ad">
              Admitted to
            </button>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I do not understand why it works the first time but not in a different window, the lines in charge of making the variables appear are:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="ad" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Admission(s)</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">

                    <li class="list-group-item">

                      <xsl:value-of select="$examG"/>

                    </li>

                  </div>
```

Thank you !
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGFAe.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBy9a.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gS9hI.png

Answer (score 0):

I think it is more about generating a meaningful HTML structure for multiples students, you can't use the same `id` attribute for all of them, you will need to have separate id values, in XSLT you can generate them with by calling `generate-id()`.

So for instance using `<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#{generate-id()}">` instead of `<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#id">` and then having a dialogue for each id with e.g.

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="{generate-id()}" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Admission(s)</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">

            <li class="list-group-item">

              <xsl:value-of select="$examG"/>

            </li>

          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I am not sure, however, the above captures your intended dialogue structure, hopefully it at least allows you to get some better understanding of my suggestion.

Comment: Hi ! Thank you for your reply, I didn't succeeded in implenting it, it's the first I am coding something, I looked on internet but I am probably using it wrong because an error occurs everytime